# django_heroku not found when running local server, deployed site works fine

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I've just deployed my site with heroku and it seems to be working fine. I tried going back to my regular localhost:8000 to make some changes without having to wait for the push every time, but it now gives me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

I have

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

in my settings.py and when running `pip freeze` I get

```
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.5
```

Everything seems to be working fine, although when trying to pip install psycopg2 I run into another error

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

My heroku app seems to be working fine, but I can't get the localhost:8000 to run again, is there something I can do here?

Comment: Where do you try to run your localhost server? Via your IDE? Did you check if the python path is set correctly?

Comment: I'm running ```python manage.py runserver``` from my mac terminal. I found a temporary workaround, if I comment out the django_heroku-lines and switch the secret keys, it seems to be running fine.